# CD to Auto-Open Webpage

Tags: windows, macos, cd, autorun

A friend of mine wants to hand out CDs (yes, compact disks) as invitations for a party.  When someone puts the CD into their computer, it should automatically load a webpage used for RSVPing to the party.  How can I go about getting this done?

I know Windows has a default browser stored somewhere that I think can be used without worrying about cross platform issues, is this correct?  What about Apple users?

Comment: I run Linux, and if my invitation doesn't work I'm **definitely** not going to the party.

Comment: Don't depend on Autorun for anything. If the CD is only being used to launch a web page, you're better off writing a [ShortURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) on a scrap of paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Windows very simply, but supporting Linux/OS X will be harder.
Windows `Autorun.inf` support does what you want - all you need is a URL to be opened and it will open in the user's default browser:

```
Shellexecute=http://mypartyinvite.com
```

On OS X you could use a `.webloc` file. The user would still need to open the CD and double-click on the file, but then the OS will handle opening the link inside the user's default browser.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>http://mypartyinvite.com</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

On Linux I don't know what you'd do, perhaps a shell script for the user to double-click that cleverly determined the environment and made an educated guess at the browser to open?

Comment: Do *you* have autorun support enabled on your computer? I don't see this very often.

Comment: Yes? It's on by default in all versions of Windows that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a a bad idea.** *Everyone* should have autorun functionality disabled on their computer, and any decent virus scanner will throw a fit if a CD attempts to automatically navigate to a web page.

> I know Windows has a default browser stored somewhere that I think can be used without worrying about cross platform issues, is this correct?

No, that's not correct. It doesn't make much sense, either. You can't rely on a feature present in Windows to alleviate cross-platform issues. Windows is a single platform.

> What about Apple users?

There is no such thing as "Apple" users. But no, it won't work for them either. Mac OS X just flat doesn't support this feature. It was semi-supported through QuickTime in previous versions of the Mac OS (i.e., Mac OS 9 and earlier), but it was considered so vile, exploitable, and ill-behaved by Mac users that
Apple just ripped it from OS X entirely.

**Find another way to invite people to your party.** Finally a compelling use for Facebook or Twitter!